# Maximizing likelihood function in Matlab for logistic regression

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I've been studying the problem of logistic regression theoretically (math theory) and now I would like to implement it using maximum likelihood estimation. We have the function of maximum likelihood, which looks this way

```
function P = maximumLikelihood(beta, X, y)

P = 1;
m = size(X,1);
for i=1:m
if y(i) == 0
    currP = 1 - sigmoid(X(i,:)*beta);
else
    currP = sigmoid(X(i,:)*beta);
end
P = currP*P;
end

end
```

I maximize it using built-in Matlab function fminbnd this way

```
fminbnd(@(beta)-maximumLikelihood(initial_beta,X,y), -Inf, +Inf)
```

It gives me 3 beta values, which I use for my sigmoid function to make predictions. However, I have a very high error rate, more than 50% of data are misclassified. Please tell me if I made something wrong or if I maximized the function in the wrong way; I haven't found any code on the Internet, only theory about maximum likelihood function and built-in Matlab function for logistic regression.

Comment: It looks like your handle for the function to minimize is incorrect.  You are providing `initial_beta` when it should be `beta`.  `fminbnd` provides guesses as to what the best `beta` should be and you provide a function that takes in these guesses so that it can determine the best direction to move to minimize the cost function.  `initial_beta` never changes and so the minimization (maximization rather in your case) never happens.  Try changing `initial_beta` to `beta` in your line of code and see what happens.

Comment: Also, it would help if you provided the following: (1) Your training data and labels. (2) What your initial `beta` was. (3) Any other code so that we can run this in full and see what the problems are.

Comment: @rayryeng I've changed     initial_beta     to     beta, but it changed nothing. I see that for another dataset the code doesn't work, I have 4 variables and 1 intercept (the first column). I see that the error happens when I calculate P = currP*P; for some reason currP isn't scalar, but a matrix consisting of 5 elements, just like the beta does (I set its value to [0;0;0;0;0]). So I can multiply P and currP only using transpose, but the code still doesn't work, values of beta become 1 or 0 and so I can't make any predictions. I would be grateful for your help.